# Tooltip is not showing for disabled listbox item in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I have a list of items and each of those are button control. When i click any of the list box item, i made it to be disabled. for those disabled items, unable to see tooltip message

```
    public class ListBoxTemplate : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var buttonFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
        buttonFactory.SetValue(Control.NameProperty, "Button");
        buttonFactory.SetValue(Button.WidthProperty, Double.NaN);
        buttonFactory.SetValue(Button.HeightProperty, Double.NaN);
        Binding bindingPath = new Binding();
        buttonFactory.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, bindingPath);
        buttonFactory.SetValue(ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabledProperty, true);
        Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
        trigger.Property = Control.IsEnabledProperty;
        trigger.Value = true;
        Setter setter = new Setter();
        setter.Property = Control.ToolTipProperty;
        setter.Value = "Your tooltip";
        trigger.Setters.Add(setter);

        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = buttonFactory };
        template.Triggers.Add(trigger);
        return template;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ListBoxTemplate x:Key="templateSelector"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="list" Height="100" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" >



</ListBox>
```

Comment: Why are you using a DataTemplateSelector? You can do this in a simple way by using ListBox.ItemTemplate as Button with ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabledProperty as true

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line to display tooltip

```
buttonFactory.SetValue(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, "My Tooltip");
```